# What role does Virginia Woolf play in "Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf?"

Tags: edward-albee, whos-afraid-of-virginia-woolf

To me, it seems that Albee's play is expressly about a married couple who attempt to psychologically destroy each other. I understand that the title is a play on the phrase, "Who's afraid of the big bad wolf?" but how does Virginia Woolf replace the big bad wolf in this play? Moreover, how does Virginia Woolf tie into this marriage and, more importantly, this story?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the SparkNotes Study Guide for the play](https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/afraidofwoolf/section5/), Virginia Woolf's work frequently exposed the reality behind fantasies, shining a light on dark truths. Much of George and Martha's marriage is based on the fantasy games they play with each other. Thus, she fears "Virginia Woolf" in that she does not want to face the reality of her marriage and life.

> The climax of the play reveals the extent to which invention is featured in the story. Their son is made up, as is, perhaps, the story from George's childhood about his friend who accidentally killed his parents. The idea behind the "Exorcism" (the title of the final act) is that the characters are getting rid of the illusions. To "exorcise" means to rid one's body of evil spirits. Therefore, in terms of the play, no more will George and Martha exist in a land of fantasy and make-believe. Still, Martha fears the amount of reality involved in this life. She is afraid of Virginia Woolf, who tried to expose reality and the sincerity of emotion.

This is backed up by the words of Albee himself, according to [Wikipedia's article on the play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_Afraid_of_Virginia_Woolf%3F#Reality_and_illusion):

> Albee has said that the title of the play "means who’s afraid of the big bad wolf … who’s afraid of living life without false illusions."

Comment: The interview from which Wikipedia quoted that line about the title is available in full in [*Writers at Work: the Paris Review interviews, third series*, p. 331](https://archive.org/details/writersatworkpar00burr/page/330/mode/2up).